# Fill only x percent of the background of a view in android?

Tags: android

In android , i want to fill only a part of the background (for example 70% from right or left) of a view by a color like black programitically.
How can I do that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: you can calculate the width and height of the background, then change its hight and width by setLyaoutParams()

Comment: Use GradientDrawable for this, it will help

Answer (score 0):

You could use (shape, gradient) to achieve this effect.
Android set the background color can be defined in a xml res/drawable, 
as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#000"
        android:startColor="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

Shape is used to define the shape, gradient inside the definition of the shape of the gradient fill, startColor starting color, endColor end color, angle indicates the direction angle. When the angle = 0, the gradient from left to right.

Then set shape to view background.

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Comment: I want to do it programitically.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a BitmapDrawable 10px wide @1px high, fill it with Color.TRANSPARENT and then draw a line from 0,0 to x,0 using your desired colour. Use Canvas to achieve all that.

Then call yourcontrol.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmap) an you're done